# Calcular distância entre dois pontos pela latitude e longitude

Tags: delphi, matemática, equações

Preciso calcular a distância em quilômetro(Km) entre dois pontos através da latitude e da longitude deles. Não encontrei uma maneira eficaz de fazer.

As latitudes e longitudes que tenho estão formatadas da seguinte maneira:

> lat: -29.6518875
>
> long: -51.1716005

Encontrei maneiras de calculá-las quando estão em graus, mas nada quando estão nesta formatação.

Comment: http://www.tdevrocks.com.br/2014/09/26/quick-post-como-saber-a-distancia-entre-dois-pontos-no-mapa/ veja se isso te ajuda.

Comment: Irei testar, obrigado.

Comment: @R.Gasparin basta marcar a solução como aceita, não precisa e nem deve mexer no título.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente este código comigo resultou:

```
function sgn(a: real): real;
begin
  if a < 0 then sgn := -1 else sgn := 1;
end;

function atan2(y, x: real): real;
begin
  if x > 0  then atan2 := arctan(y/x)
  else if x < 0  then atan2 := arctan(y/x) + pi
  else atan2 := pi/2 * sgn(y);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Long1, Lat1, Long2, Lat2, Val1, Val2, Long, Lat: Double;
begin
  Lat1 := 41.500605;
  Long1 := -7.731313;
  Lat2 := 37.186851;
  Long2 := -8.742056;

  Lat1 := Lat1 * pi / 180.0;
  Long1 := Long1 * pi / 180.0;
  Lat2 := Lat2 * pi / 180.0;
  Long2 := Long2 * pi / 180.0;

  Lat := Lat2 - Lat1;
  Long := Long2 - Long1;

  Val1 := 6371.0;
  Val2 := sin(Lat / 2) * sin(Lat / 2) + cos(Lat1) * cos(Lat2) * sin(Long / 2) * sin(Long / 2);
  Val2 := 2 * ATan2(sqrt(Val2), sqrt(1 - Val2));

  Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(Val1 * Val2) + ' KM');
end;
```

Alguma questão ou duvida coloque, mais informações sobre a fórmula pode consultar [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: Não estou conseguindo compreender estas variáveis e de onde vieram estes números, está confuso.

Comment: São as equações necessárias para chegar a solução, não sei como explicar melhor que isso.

Comment: Posso tentar atribuir novas variáveis mais explicitas, e tentar explicar melhor todo o processo.. chegou a testar?

Comment: Deixo aqui este Link, que foi por onde me guiei: www.tdevrocks.com.br/2014/09/26/quick-post-como-saber-a-distancia-entre-dois-pontos-no-mapa/

Comment: Não entendo de onde surgem estes nomes, por isso é confuso. O que significa W1 por exemplo.

Comment: Não testei ainda, gostaria de entender melhor estas questões que citei para poder implementar na minha aplicação.

Comment: Tentei melhorar o código quando poder de uma vista de olhos

Comment: Agora está melhor de compreender, testei e funciona. Obrigado!

Comment: Se não tiver mais nenhuma dúvida ou questão e se a sua pergunta foi respondida, deve então atribuir o seu feedback a minha resposta e fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que a solução seja a fórmula "harvesine": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: Tem certeza que a distancia foi calculada corretamente?

Comment: @RicardodaRochaVitor tem mais de um jeito de calcular geodésica, o "certo" depende de muitos fatores. Se quer mais precisão que Haversine, precisa usar Vincenty, por exemplo. Se quer mais precisão ainda, precisa aplicar o algoritmo mais adequado para a região certa, e isso varia muito. Hoje usamos WGS84 pra quase tudo, mas não é toda região que fica tão bom.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código completo baseado na contribuição do colega Tmc, pronto para testar

## Em um formulário em branco:

copie o código abaixo e pressione Ctrl+V (Colar)

```
object Edit1: TEdit
  Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
  TabOrder = 0
  KeyboardType = NumberPad
  Text = '41.500605'
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 56.0
  TextPrompt = 'Latitude1'
end
object Edit2: TEdit
  Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
  TabOrder = 1
  KeyboardType = NumberPad
  Text = '-7,731313'
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 80.0
  TextPrompt = 'Longitude1'
end
object Edit3: TEdit
  Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
  TabOrder = 2
  KeyboardType = NumberPad
  Text = '37,186851'
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 128.0
  TextPrompt = 'Latitude2'
end
object Edit4: TEdit
  Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
  TabOrder = 3
  KeyboardType = NumberPad
  Text = '-8,742056'
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 152.0
  TextPrompt = 'Longitude2'
end
object Button1: TButton
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 184.0
  TabOrder = 4
  Text = 'Distancia'
  OnClick = Button1Click
end
object Label1: TLabel
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 40.0
  Text = 'Coordenada A'
end
object Label2: TLabel
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 112.0
  Text = 'Coordenada B'
end
object Label3: TLabel
  Position.X = 56.0
  Position.Y = 216.0
end
```

Colo o seguinte codigo abaixo de **implementation**, em seguida pressione Shift+Ctrl+C para criar as assinaturas

```
  function CalcDistanciaCoord(Lat1,Lng1,Lat2,Lng2:Double):Double;//Retorna distancia em Km
    const
           r:Double = 6371.0;//Raio da terra
    var
           Val, Lng, Lat: Double;
           piLat1,piLng1,piLat2,piLng2:Double;

    function sgn(a: real): real;
    begin
    //if a < 0 then sgn := -1 else sgn := 1;
        result := a/abs(a)
    end;

    function atan2(y, x: real): real;
    begin
      if x > 0  then atan2 := arctan(y/x)
      else if x < 0  then atan2 := arctan(y/x) + pi
          else atan2 := pi/2 * sgn(y);
    end;

begin
  piLat1 := Lat1 * pi / 180.0;
  piLng1 := Lng1 * pi / 180.0;
  piLat2 := Lat2 * pi / 180.0;
  piLng2 := Lng2 * pi / 180.0;

  Lat := Lat2 - Lat1;
  Lng := Lng2 - Lng1;

  Val := sin(Lat / 2) * sin(Lat / 2) + cos(Lat1) * cos(Lat2) * sin(Lng / 2) * sin(Lng / 2);
  Val := 2 * ATan2(sqrt(Val), sqrt(1 - Val));

  Result:= r * Val;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var d,La1,Lo1,La2,Lo2:Double;
    begin
    La1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.text);
    Lo1 := StrToFloat(Edit2.text);
    La2 := StrToFloat(Edit3.text);
    Lo2 := StrToFloat(Edit4.text);
    d:=CalcDistanciaCoord(La1,Lo1,La2,Lo2);
    label3.text:=formatfloat('#0.000000 Km',d);
    //label1.caption:=formatfloat('#0.000000 Km",d);//VCL
    end;
```

Comment: Pelo que verifiquei no google MAPS o cálculo está errado. Alguém pode verificar?

Comment: Não vai bater com o google (claro que é para aproximar), pois Haversine é uma aproximação muito "arredondada". Se quer mais precisão, precisa usar outras fórmulas e estratégias. E para calcular distância real, precisa usar o mapa do terreno, o que foge um pouco da pergunta, creio eu. Dois pares de coordenadas podem ter distâncias diferentes se ambos estão num deserto ou cada um do lado de uma montanha.

Comment: Mas a diferença está muitoo grande... 10424,16... Contra 562Km, então tem algum erro nas equacoes, pode verificar?

Comment: Precisa pegar a fórmula original (Haversine) e comparar. Aí acha onde errou. Pode ser alguma bobeira de parâmetro errado.